# jQuery: get the first 25 string characters including single space of an element?

Tags: jquery

The problem I have is when I get the `text()` of an element I end up with all this white space and line spacings.

I just want the first 25 string characters (counting single spaces) of the `text()` by doing

```
$(element).text(/  /g,'').substring(0,25)
```

however this seems to also count the empty line spacings. however I want to preserve single spaces, just don't need the text with it's formatting in full glory, and need only the first 25 characters including single space.

Comment: Confusing. What's the difference you see between white space and single space?

Comment: Do you mean `$(element).text().replace(/  /g,'')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(element).text().trim().replace(/\s+/g,' ').slice(0,24)
```

`text()` to get text content
`trim()` to remove spaces at starting and end
`replace()` to replace white spaces to single space
`slice()` to cut upto 25 charactor

Also you can use `.substr(0,25)`

```
$(element).text().trim().replace(/\s+/g,' ').substr(0,25)
```

Comment: this is a good answer but it seems to now be removing the beginning of a text

Comment: it will remove space at the beginning

Comment: `<div class="si_highlighted" id="blurb">Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required.<br>
            <br>
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/about" class="button" id="tell-me-more">Take the 2-minute tour</a>
        </div>` returns `"tion and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required. Take the 2-minute tour"` it seems to have removed the beginning text

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
$(element).text(/\s+/g,' ').substring(0,25)
```

`\s` - stands for any white-space character
`\s+` - stands for a sequence of white-space characters